# What to use Multi-level Classification for Machine Learning predicting target Y1 and Y2

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-modeling

I have the data set where different signals are there. where it may be single or double or in groups so there are two outcomes where one outcome is dependent on the other.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['signal']= ['P03' , 'U01 U30', 'P03 P02 P04', 'P04 P03', 'P03', 'U007', 'T0U', 'K050 A078', 'T0V','T0X T0U T0V']
df['MR'] = ['Bat','ECG','Bat','Bat','O2','Circuit','Cylin','Cylin2','EGR','Pad']
df['DC'] = ['Op or Kp','Mett','Op or Kp','Val','Crack','Op or Kp', 'Wire','Val','Op or Kp','Op or Kp']
```

Let's consider for machine learning model I have x input is `signal` and there are two outputs `MR` and `DC` .. I want to predict the `DC` but it is directly dependent on `MR`. `Op or Kp` is related to any signals but want to predict for where signals is matching with `MR`...
Let see If i take a Input as `P03` then It should predict `Op or Kp`,`Val`,`Crack`, - First come 'Op or Kp' coz it comes two times where `P03` is present. and then rest two.
but with respect MR where it is showing `bat` and `O2`. So I want to predict the `DC` `(y1)` and `MR` `(y2)`.. where `y1` is dependent on `y2`. 
Which algorithms should we consider or what should I search?
In Traditional machine learning there should be only one Y output but there are two and one is dependent on second one. Not getting idea How can I do it?
If someone can imporve this question will really helps and thank you in advance..
addition of this question link may help you to clear more.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265598/how-to-train-machine-learning-algorithm-with-two-target-y1-and-y2

Expected output

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you need statistical ML for this? If you have only a small set of possibilities, it's  more efficient to just do a small code with a few if..then. You could also have a dict which maps the input to the output. Anyway if you really want a classification system for this, you can simply train two models in this case, especially if you want the output of one to be used as input of the other.

Comment: @Erwan : This is not small dataset. and required things is I want to predict y1(MR) - which probability should between for each 0 to 1. and for y2 (DC) it is between 0 to 1 with respective MR

Comment: Technically the probability can be obtained just by dividing the count by the total. Anyway if you want you could train a decision tree classifier for the first variable, then another one for the second variable adding the first predicted value as a feature.

Comment: @Erwan I will try .. will let you know

Comment: @Erwan can you suggest or refer any code files for this type on internet?

Comment: You can use [sklearn decision tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification) for instance, it's very well documented with easy visualization of the model.

Comment: @Erwan Thank you